# Installing Drush over SSH messed up my Vagrant config

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile, drush

I have no idea what happened so I'm not going to act like I do.

I installed drush over Vagrant SSH from one of my site directories so that I could clear my cache from the command line.

Now, any command I run from vagrant returns `alias: drush: not found`.

I cannot access my local databases through MySQL; I cannot vagrant provision; I cannot access vagrant SSH.

Will someone please help?

Comment: You probably have something wrong in your Vagrantfile. if you can put your file here, it'd be easier to help. Also you can try to remove provisioning part, etc so with minimal file to make sure it works and then add one by one the different elements

Comment: Cleaned up format and fixed typo.